# Allow traffic from single IP address, block all other addresses

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, ipsec, windows

I have a server running Windows Server 2003. I want to only allow traffic from my IP address and block all other traffic from all other addresses. I'd like to know how to correctly configure this IP Security Policy using the MMC within Windows.

Comment: Before you block all traffic you should keep in mind that this will also block all access to your domain controllers, the internet, etc.  You'll be better off changing the ACLs on your router or your firewall to block access, then setup a VPN tunnel into the server so that you can connect securly.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. It's a hosted VPS and I need to connect to it from only my machine, so I intentionally want it blocked from the internet except for my connections. Unfortunately I don't have access to the router or firewalls as it's hosted by a third party.

Comment: They can't setup these rules for you?  That's a much more secure way to go.  I can't provide ipsec directions as I do everything at the firewall level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best place to start is at the Microsoft TechNet [IPsec page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb531150.aspx). It's fairly simple to set up a local IPsec policy that will accept packets from a single address only. I think you'll need two rules:

Rule 1

- Filter list with one filter: from
  any-address:any-port to
  my-address:any-port
- Filter action:
  block Rule: link the list with the
  action; all interfaces; no tunnel;
  any authentication method

Rule 2

- Filter list with two filters: from
  your-workstation-address:any-port to
  my-address:any-port
- Filter action: permit
- Rule: link the list with the action; all interfaces; no tunnel; any authentication method